# How to use threading and sudo in fabric 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fabric, python-fabric-2

My question is the same as this one, but I'm not thrilled with the only answer. [fabric 2.3 parallel execution of sudo commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187967/fabric-2-3-parallel-execution-of-sudo-commands)

Hoping there are other opinions out there?

I'm trying to migrate my Python 2/Fabric 1 code to Python 3/Fabric 2. The code performs a lot of tasks in parallel and runs commands as root on the remote machines. This worked in Fabric 1 but I am having trouble getting this to work with Fabric 2.

The ThreadingGroup class provides the parallelism I want, but does not have a sudo method. I tried implementing the answer from the original question, which is to copy the run method from ThreadingGroup, make a few changes, and call it "sudo". This didn't work for me, saying I need a tty to sudo.

I also submitted my question to the fabric mailing list. I will update my question here if I get a response from them.